# Is there any way to reduce the time taken to select around 2000+ files? It takes around 4-5 minutes just to select the files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html, user-interface

I am building an UI functionality where I can be able to upload more than 2000 images at once. 
   I am facing a problem with file selection. When I am selecting more than 2000 images in one go using CMD A, it starts showing the browser busy indicator and takes around 4-5 minutes for the same.

First i thought, it may be because of rendering the image previews of the 2000 images might be taking time. I removed that, but still nothing happened.
Then I also removed the validation which I was doing on the file types and file sizes. But still no luck.
So not able to figure out where is the issue?

```
handleFileSelect = () => {
    if (this.file && this.file.files.length > 0) {
      this.setState({
        fileSelected: true,
        progress: {},
        filesCount: this.file.files.length
      });
      // this.validateFiles();
    }
  };

<input
   id="fileUploadButton"
   className="default-file-button"
   ref={fileInput => {
     this.file = fileInput;
   }}
   type="file"
   accept={this.props.accept}
   multiple
   onChange={this.handleFileSelect}
   name="image"
/>
```

So, I am just wondering if it is known behaviour for browsers to get stuck after selection of more than thousand images.

Comment: Not only images, if you are supposed to select 2000 files in one go, then obv there is going to be some load.

Comment: Did you try removing `onChange` handler? IMO, this does not seem like a `reactJS` related issue.

Comment: @Rayon I tried removing that, but still the issue persists.

Comment: Check your memory state. I think the files will be cached as binary in the browser cache.

Comment: I deleted the browser cache and system cache as well. but no luck. Also, one thing which I noticed, this issue only exists on my system. I tested my application on other similar systems, its pretty fast, happening in seconds.